# How to use javascript to trigger a css event for a collection of elements that have the same class/name

Tags: javascript, css, events

says it all really in the title I have this javascript

```
<script>          
$(".tile").click(function(e){
 $(this).toggleClass("flipOutX")  ; 
})
</script>
```

I have some html dfined boxes called "tile" and the problem here is that when i click an individual tile the flipoutx function works but only the tile I have clicked....

How can I make this work for all my tiles that are all called "tile" and not just the one tile I have clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ...

```
$(".tile").click(function(e) {
  $(".tile").toggleClass("flipOutX"); 
});
```

The change of the `$(this)` (single tile) to `$(".tile")` (collection of elements) is what allows for all tiles to move when one is clicked.

Simple change in what you are referencing.  Instead of referencing the `.tile` clicked with *this*, you need to reference the `tile`(s).

Comment: YES ! this worked thank you very much.... If i have a sub function to flipOutX called eight for example can I add that in aswell so that both flipoutx and eight happen ?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking; yes, you should also be able to fire another function inside the click function.  You can also fire that against `$(".tile")` as defined here.

Comment: As all my tiles are defined as the same class "tile" I want them all to have  a transition delay for each tile that I have defined in css so the function is performed on each tile sequentially... so my html for the class of each tile is slightly different currently to accomodate a transition delay on page load but I want the same in reverse for when a tile is clicked.                         This is the line off one of my tiles      -----------   <div class="tile double animated five flipInX" data-click="transform">             where "five" is the transition delay set for this particular tile

Comment: That's a whole new question with a different set of issues ... You should post it as a new question!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(".tile").click(function(e){
$('.tile').toggleClass("flipOutX")  ; 
})
```